# blank line created when using buffer size

Tags: c, buffer, sizeof

the original text is

```
Make me a sandwich.
What? Make it yourself.
Sudo make me a sandwich.
Okay.
```

and i have to change that

~~ like this ~~

```
Make me a sosandwich.
Whatot? Make itot yourorsoself.
SoSudo make me a sosandwich.
Okay.
```

the code is given and I add the switch statement to main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>

#define D_BUFSIZE       4096    /* size of buffer for input and output */
                                /* should be a block size, 512, 4096, 8192 */

#define NUM_ARGS_3      3
#define NUM_ARGS_4      4

#define ERROR_ARGS      1
#define ERROR_OPEN_R    2
#define ERROR_OPEN_W    3
#define ERROR_WRITE     4
#define ERROR_CALLOC    5

#define SUCCESS         0
#define ERROR           -1

int BUFSIZE = D_BUFSIZE;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input_file,
    *output_file,
    *buffer;
    int input_fd,
     output_fd;
    ssize_t return_num_bytes_write,
     return_num_bytes_read;
    off_t offset = 0;

    if (argc != NUM_ARGS_3 && argc != NUM_ARGS_4) {
        printf("Usage: %s source_file target_file [BUFSIZE]\n", argv[0]);
        return ERROR_ARGS;
    }

    if (argc == NUM_ARGS_4) {
        BUFSIZE = atoi(argv[3]);
    }

    if (argc == NUM_ARGS_3) {
        BUFSIZE = 1;
    }

    input_file = argv[1];
    output_file = argv[2];
    buffer = (char *) calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        return ERROR_CALLOC;
    }

    input_fd = open(input_file, O_RDONLY);
    if (input_fd == ERROR) {
        perror("open");
        return ERROR_OPEN_R;
    }

    output_fd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (output_fd == ERROR) {
        perror("open");
        return ERROR_OPEN_W;
    }
    while ((return_num_bytes_read = read(input_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE)) >= 0) {
        if (return_num_bytes_read == 0) {
            break;
        }
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
            switch (buffer[i]) {
            case 'R':
                write(output_fd, "RoR", 3);
                break;
            case 'r':
                write(output_fd, "ror", 3);
                break;
            case 'S':
                write(output_fd, "SoS", 3);
                break;
            case 's':
                write(output_fd, "sos", 3);
                break;
            case 'T':
                write(output_fd, "ToT", 3);
                break;
            case 't':
                write(output_fd, "tot", 3);
                break;
            default:
                write(output_fd, &buffer[i], 1);
            }
        }
        if (return_num_bytes_read == ERROR) {
            perror("read");
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

it runs kinda correctly, but the problem is
there is extra empty line at the bottom

```
Make me a sosandwich.
Whatot? Make itot yourorsoself.
SoSudo make me a sosandwich.
Okay.
(blank line created here)
```

// -------------------

there should be no empty line in the bottom and like

```
Make me a sosandwich.
Whatot? Make itot yourorsoself.
SoSudo make me a sosandwich.
Okay.
```

so when i compare those two files with diff command,
then it said differ and i think it is because of blank line at the bottom.

i could not find what is the problem that the empty line at the bottom created.

how can i edit it to make the correct result?

Comment: `for (i=0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)` Change to: `for (i = 0; i < return_num_bytes_read; i++)`... You only want to deal with as many characters as have been loaded... (And, it's common to "Accept" answers to questions that help solve your problems. Just sayin'...)

Comment: Why are you doing raw I/O?  Use stdio (fread, fwrite, fprintf, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded, built, and ran your program.

I got binary garbage at the end. But, I used a buffer size of 1000. So, the trailing text/data varies depending upon the buffer size we use.

You're defining a buffer of a certain size (a VLA array). So, `sizeof(buffer)` is for the *entire* buffer rather than the amount gotten from the `read` call.

If we specify 10,000 as the buffer length, and the input text is (e.g.) only 75 bytes, we'll append 9,925 extra bytes. Because `buffer` is on the stack, any bytes not filled in by the `read` will "random".

So, we want to apply a fix [as Fe2O3 suggested].

Change:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
```

Into:

```
for (i = 0; i < return_num_bytes_read; i++) {
```

---

Also, if we should add `O_TRUNC` to the `open` for output.

If we don't delete the output file first, and we run the program twice, once with an input file of (e.g.) 500 bytes.

And, a second run with a *smaller* input file (e.g. 200 bytes) that outputs to the *same* output file, the result will have "leftover" characters from the bottom part of the first input file.

---

Here is the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>

#define D_BUFSIZE       4096    /* size of buffer for input and output */
                                /* should be a block size, 512, 4096, 8192 */

#define NUM_ARGS_3      3
#define NUM_ARGS_4      4

#define ERROR_ARGS      1
#define ERROR_OPEN_R    2
#define ERROR_OPEN_W    3
#define ERROR_WRITE     4
#define ERROR_CALLOC    5

#define SUCCESS         0
#define ERROR           -1

int BUFSIZE = D_BUFSIZE;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input_file,
    *output_file,
    *buffer;
    int input_fd,
     output_fd;
    ssize_t return_num_bytes_write,
     return_num_bytes_read;
    off_t offset = 0;

    if (argc != NUM_ARGS_3 && argc != NUM_ARGS_4) {
        printf("Usage: %s source_file target_file [BUFSIZE]\n", argv[0]);
        return ERROR_ARGS;
    }

    if (argc == NUM_ARGS_4) {
        BUFSIZE = atoi(argv[3]);
    }

    if (argc == NUM_ARGS_3) {
        BUFSIZE = 1;
    }

    input_file = argv[1];
    output_file = argv[2];
    buffer = (char *) calloc(BUFSIZE, sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        return ERROR_CALLOC;
    }

    input_fd = open(input_file, O_RDONLY);
    if (input_fd == ERROR) {
        perror("open");
        return ERROR_OPEN_R;
    }

#if 0
    output_fd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
#else
    output_fd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
#endif
    if (output_fd == ERROR) {
        perror("open");
        return ERROR_OPEN_W;
    }
    while ((return_num_bytes_read = read(input_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE)) >= 0) {
        if (return_num_bytes_read == 0) {
            break;
        }
        int i;

#if 0
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
#else
        for (i = 0; i < return_num_bytes_read; i++) {
#endif
            switch (buffer[i]) {
            case 'R':
                write(output_fd, "RoR", 3);
                break;
            case 'r':
                write(output_fd, "ror", 3);
                break;
            case 'S':
                write(output_fd, "SoS", 3);
                break;
            case 's':
                write(output_fd, "sos", 3);
                break;
            case 'T':
                write(output_fd, "ToT", 3);
                break;
            case 't':
                write(output_fd, "tot", 3);
                break;
            default:
                write(output_fd, &buffer[i], 1);
            }
        }
        if (return_num_bytes_read == ERROR) {
            perror("read");
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the output I got after the fixes:

```
Make me a sosandwich.
Whatot? Make itot yourorsoself.
SoSudo make me a sosandwich.
Okay.
```

Comment: Betting that your `O_TRUNC` was the magic elixir that solved this problem... `:-)`